# AMD - want to load viewModel when main.js is called instead of defining each view model in require.configure.js

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, requirejs, amd

While using MVC and requireJs for AMD i am stuck in a problem where i want to load the view-model script when the main script file for respective module is called instead of defining all the view-models in require.configure.js

Here is the Sequence of Code:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
          "~/Scripts/Common/require.configure.js",
          "~/Scripts/Common/require.js"));
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@section scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")}
<script data-main="Scripts/BookService/Testing/HomeMain"></script>
```

**require.configure.js**

```
var require = {
baseUrl: "/",
paths: {
    "bootstrap": "Scripts/Common/bootstrap",
    "jquery": "Scripts/Common/jquery-1.10.2",
    "knockout": "Scripts/Common/knockout-3.3.0",
    "knockout-projections": "Scripts/Common/knockout-projections.min",
    "domready": "Scripts/Common/domReady",
    /////////View Models///////////////////////////////////////
    "HomeViewModel": "Scripts/BookService/Testing/HomeViewModel"
},
shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    }
}}
```

**HomeMain.js**

```
require(['knockout', 'HomeViewModel'], function (ko, appViewModel) {
ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());});
```

**HomeViewModel.js**

```
define(['jquery','knockout'], function ($,ko) {
       return function appViewModel() {
      //viewModel here
}

});
```

**Scripts File hierarchy:**

[image: Scripts File hierarchy :]

Comment: require path configuration is just configuration for resolution of paths by require. Think of it as an alias (they are not simply aliases though), So u can actually use the full path instead of using one word module name in HomeMain.js. If I am misundestanding, please elaborate...

Comment: @Vishwanath yes i can use the full path in HomeMain.js but what i actually need is first load the require configuration after this i want to load another JS file where i will define all the viewModel paths before loading HomeJS after this i will just give the name of viewModel in define function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use require.config for adding to config at run time. I am not sure if this is officially supported (will try to find references), but when I tried it worked.

Use it like following to add new paths to your config whenever you want.

```
require.config({
   paths : {
        "HomeViewModel" : '/path/to/homeviewmodel'
   }
});
```

Take care of the absolute and relative path as per requirement.

Comment: Thanx! @Vishwanath yes this is a way provided by RequireJs to add path later on.